# MongoDb, and YCSB: workload A: why update latency is so small?

Tags: linux, mongodb, latency, ycsb

I am running MongoDb and YCSB, Workload A (Read: Update = 50:50) on two nodes which are connected by 10G Ethernet.

The ycsb output result looks good, but only one thing: why latency for update is that small? Is update latency only include MongoDb local operation latency?

For example, in below run, the update latency is just about 4 micro-seconds. But my network latency is 100+ micro-seconds. So this looks weird to me.

thanks!

```
YCSB Client 0.1
Command line: -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.AsyncMongoDbClient -s -P LisWorkloadA -p mongodb.url=mongodb://192.168.4.168:27017/ycsb?w=0 -threads 1 -t
mongo connection created with mongodb://192.168.4.168:27017/ycsb?w=0
18:09:22.758 [Thread-1] DEBUG c.a.m.c.c.b.BootstrapConnectionFactory - Simple MongoDB bootstrap to 192.168.4.168/192.168.4.168:27017.
18:24:23.109 [Thread-1] DEBUG c.a.mongodb.client.ClientImpl - MongoDB Connection closed: MongoDB(56194-->192.168.4.168/192.168.4.168:27017)
[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 900433.0
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 2878.1730567404793
[READ], Operations, 1296287.0

***[READ], AverageLatency(us), 687.2264621954861***

[READ], MinLatency(us), 105.0
[READ], MaxLatency(us), 5455871.0
[READ], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 1220.0
[READ], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 1749.0
[READ], Return=OK, 1296287
[CLEANUP], Operations, 1.0
[CLEANUP], AverageLatency(us), 1672.0
[CLEANUP], MinLatency(us), 1672.0
[CLEANUP], MaxLatency(us), 1672.0
[CLEANUP], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 1672.0
[CLEANUP], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 1672.0
[UPDATE], Operations, 1295315.0

***[UPDATE], AverageLatency(us), 4.323250329070535***

[UPDATE], MinLatency(us), 1.0
[UPDATE], MaxLatency(us), 42015.0
[UPDATE], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 6.0
[UPDATE], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 10.0
[UPDATE], Return=NOT_FOUND, 1295315
```

Comment: Maybe it is a clue that all the returns of your update operations are  'NOT_FOUND', not 'Status.OK'.

Comment: Yes. but how to get rid of the "NOT_FOUND" from the ycsb command line? Looks like we need to do some settings on the parameters to specify the key range?

Comment: I don't have experience with ```AsyncMongoDbClient```, only MongoDbClient. I guess that the latency is not accurate， and when you read, maybe the write ops didn't take effect yet.

Answer (score 0):

10G Ethernet can have latencies as low as 2 microseconds, so the numbers reported by MongoDB are possible. Are you sure your 100+ microseconds measurement is correct? It may be including some overhead.

Comment: I am running the test on a virtualized environment (Linux on HyperV). the network latency between 2 VMs is 100+ ms. //Also icmp ping shows the similar latency of 100+ ms.